# cPanel - prevent addon user from accessing main root

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, add-on-domain

I have an unlimited cPanel shared hosting account, which I stopped using since I moved on to VPS. I can still access the account, and kept the files undeleted as a backup. Since I have addons enabled, I though I can allow some other people to host their sites on my account (yes, I can run a shared hosting service using my VPS, but I try to keep it isolated and lightweight).

But the problem is, when I tried to access the cPanel of one of my existing addon domains, I was able to access the document root of my main site. This means if I setup an addon domain for somebody else, they might be able to access the main root also. How to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...they might be able to access the main root also

Yes, that is how cPanel's Addon domains work. They are simply additional (ie. "add-on") domains on the main account. You can't restrict access.

In order to restrict access, you would need to create another "account". eg. As a "reseller".

Related question:
[with PHP: How to restrict access from one Addon domain to another?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81603/with-php-how-to-restrict-access-from-one-addon-domain-to-another)

Comment: I had issues with subdomains and certificate, so the hosting company told me to use addon domains, for which I had to pay extra.  The certificate now works, but I have this problem.  Why cant I put a rule in htaccess which does a redirect from maindomain/addonfolder to addondomain.  I tried but it doesn work for me.

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, you can implement a redirect in `.htaccess` to do as you require. But that is a very different requirement than stated in this question. If you have another question regarding a redirect then please ask another question.

Comment: @RohitGupta I see you have... https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137946/how-do-i-prevent-access-to-an-add-on-domain-as-a-subdirectory-of-the-main-domain