# How do I prevent access to an add-on domain as a subdirectory of the main domain?

Tags: htaccess, add-on-domain

I have my main domain as `example.software`.  I used to have  `example.kiwi` configured as a subdomain, but the hosting company could not get the certificate to work.

They asked me to fork out more money to have multiple sites so I could use the addon domain feature.  I did that and now the certificate works properly.   So `example.kiwi` has document root under `public_html` and I cant avoid it.  It's set to
`public_html/example.kiwi`.

But there is access from one to another.  In particular  `example.software/example.kiwi` is allowed.  I am trying to put a rule in `example.software` `.htaccess` to fix it, but it has no effect.

```
RewriteCond ^https:\/\/example\.software\/example\.kiwi$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.kiwi%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I realise now that the above is incorrect but I had also tried this

```
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^example\.software\/example\.kiwi$ [NC]
```

Is there anyway to get this to work?  Either redirect or error is fine.

Comment: The way that cPanel creates document roots for add-on domains is the worst.  It would avoid so many problems if they had the document roots in side by side parallel directories rather than in parent/child directories.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller This isn't a restriction imposed by cPanel as such, but could be a restriction imposed by the host. (All cPanel accounts I've used as far back as I remember have allowed you to create addon domain document roots outside of the main domain, ie. "side by side parallel directories" with the main domain. Although the parent/child directory setup is often the _default_, unless you manually change it.)

Comment: I better answer would probably be to tell them how to configure cPanel better then.  I had no idea that was available in cPanel.  I've never used it myself.   It is still an awful default.  I can't imagine a situation in which anybody would actually want parent/child document roots.

Comment: @MrWhite I agree with Stephen Ostermiller on this, it causes me headaches as a web host.  Do you know how to change the default?

Comment: I am with Crazy Domains and the mandatory prefix is public_html.  No matter what you do, it puts it back on.  And the help explicitly says that you are not allowed to get around it by using "../"  Even though I have a solution for now, I am dreading possible future issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond ^https:\/\/example\.software\/example\.kiwi$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.kiwi%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,QSA]
> ```

The *condition* as written doesn't make sense (it will never be successful so prevents the rule from doing anything). However, the `RewriteRule` directive would propagate the `example.kiwi` subdirectory, which is not what you require - you need to remove it.

For example, try the following instead in the root `.htaccess` file of the `example.software` domain:

```
# https://example.software/.htaccess

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.software [NC]
RewriteRule ^(example\.kiwi)(?:$|/)(.*) https://$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect a request for `https://example.software/example.kiwi/foo` to `https://example.kiwi/foo`.

The `$1` backreference simply saves repetition and captures `example.kiwi` from the first path segment in the URL-path. `$1` contains the remainder of the URL-path (if any), eg. `foo` in the above example.

The `QSA` flag is not required.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect.

---

Alternatively, you could use the following in the `/example.kiwi/.htaccess` (subdirectory) file, instead of the parent domain's root `.htaccess` file. In fact, this would be preferable if you have an existing `.htaccess` file in the addon domain, since the parent directives (that includes the redirect) could otherwise be overridden.

```
# https://example.software/example.kiwi/.htaccess

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.software [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.kiwi/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Although it may be preferable to check whether the request is *not* for the expected host (rather than *is* the main domain), since addon domains can often be accessed via the subdomain the addon domain is mapped to as well. For example:

```
# https://example.software/example.kiwi/.htaccess

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.kiwi$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.kiwi/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or, simply block access (403 Forbidden) when the requested hostname is not as expected? For example:

```
# https://example.software/example.kiwi/.htaccess

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.kiwi$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Although you may want to make sure you have canonicalised the hostname first.

---

> So `example.kiwi` has document root under `public_html` and I cant avoid it. It's set to `public_html/example.kiwi`

This might be a restriction imposed by *your* host, but ordinarily, you can set the document root of the (cPanel?) addon domain outside of the main domain's document root (at the same level in the directory tree as the main domain). And this is how it should be configured *most of the time*, unless the domains are related.

This then naturally prevents the addon domain being accessed by different hostnames.

Comment: The forbidden in the child domain works like a treat.  And thats where it belongs anayway.  I did have a better structured example I had tried in the parent, which hadnt worked.  And then I forgot It was a comparison :-)

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, using the `.htaccess` file in the addon/child domain (ie. inside the subdirectory) would be preferable to using the `.htaccess` file in the main domain's document root. I've updated my answer to state that.